# My program stops working during execution

Tags: c++

I write my code in code blocks and I get this runtime error during execution:

> Process returned (0xC0000005)

**This is my code**

I believe it has something to do with the way I call my functions

**main:**

```
int main()
{
    int LT[101],i, NI;
    float x;
for (i=0 ; i<101 ; i++)
LT[i]=i*i;
NI=find_NI(LT , x);
x=recieve_check_x();
cout<<"square root  of x is:"<<(NI+(x-LT[NI])/(2*NI));
return 0;
}
```

**rec_chk.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "funcs_hd.h"
using namespace std;
float recieve_check_x ()
{
    float x;
cout<<"enter the value of x:"<<endl;
cin>>x;
while (x<0 or x>10000)
    {
    cout<<"\a error! x must be within range of [0,10000]"<<endl;
    cout<<"enter another value:"<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    }

    }
```

**find_NI:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "funcs_hd.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
 int find_NI (int LT[] , float x)
 {
 int i, j , NI;
 j=i+1;
 double i_delta=abs(LT[i]-x);
 double j_delta=abs(LT[j]-x);
 if (i_delta<j_delta)
    NI=LT[i];
    else
    NI=LT[j];
    return NI;
 }
```

**funcs_hd:**

```
#ifndef FUNCS_HD_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCS_HD_H_INCLUDED

float recieve_check_x (void);
int find_NI (int [] , float);
#endif // FUNCS_HD_H_INCLUDED
```

I get an error code and the program stops running

Comment: Where does it stop? Does it break inside a line? Does it start at all?

Comment: Time to fire up your debugger

Comment: `0xC0000005` is the "Access Violation" on windows, the equivallent of "Segmentation fault" on unix. Which most probably means you're running into a null-pointer somewhere during execution :)

Comment: You don't actually `return x;` in `recieve_check_x`. Turning on compiler warnings would have helped you find this and various other errors.

Comment: You are using a junk value of `x, i and j`. You are trying to access a element of an array at a location given by a junk value.

Comment: There's so much possibility of undefined behavior.. Contents of `LT` are not initialized before use, and even the values, it gets initialized with are `i*i`, which can grow past the size of the array, hence `LT[NI]`, where `NI` is a value retrieved from array, might access past the end of the array.. In addition to your `find_NI` trying to `LT[i]`, or `LT[j]` where `i` is not initialized, and `j=i+1`, where `i` is not initialized.. And that's not even all of the cases of possible undefined behavior in your code..

Comment: Variables in `main()` or any other function have no connection to variables with the same name in some other function. I think you expected changing the value of `i` in main would set the value of `i` in `find_NI`. It certainly will not.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int i, j , NI;
> j=i+1;
>   ^ indeterminate value
> ```

You read an indeterminate value in the program. Therefore the behaviour of the program is undefined.